# How to get raw packet data using windows pktmon in realtime

Tags: windows, networking, packet-capture

I am trying to use `pktmon.exe` to capture and log network packets in real-time. Though `pktmon` gives the `hex` of payload output in its `.txt` and `.pcapng` files when log-mode is not set to real-time, but when I try to get the log in real-time, I only get the parsed packet info.

Is it possible to get the raw hex data of a packet via pktmon.exe when log-mode is set to real-time.

I tried the following command:

`pktmon start --capture --log-mode real-time --flags 0x010`

but was unable to get the raw data/payload of the packet.